# C program output returning 0

Tags: c

my C program showing output 0;
there is no compiler error and i can see my entered number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    double height;
    double width;
    double perimeter;
    double area;

    perimeter = 2.0 * (height+width);
    area = width * height;

    printf("Enter the height of rectangle:");
    scanf("%lf",&height);
    printf("You entered: %.2lf as height \n",height);

    printf("Enter the width of rectangle:");
    scanf("%lf",&width);
    printf("You entered: %.2lf as width \n",width);


    printf("\nthe area of rectangle is: %.2lf",area);
    printf("\nthe perimeter of rectangle is: %.2lf",perimeter);
    return 0;
}
```

outputs always 0

Comment: Put the `perimeter = 2.0 * (height+width);` after you read in those values. Same with the `area = width * height;`.

Comment: The program executes top to bottom, so you want read in the values first (`scanf`) and only then calculate the `perimeter` and `area`.

Comment: thanks got it now, such a noob mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You compute the value of perimeter and area **before** the variable they use have been initialized

Thus, these lines after your `scanf`s

```c
perimeter = 2.0 * (height+width);
area = width * height;
```

Also, note that the value of undefined variable's is not necessarily 0. It can be anything, like 2 , -42 or 546547981, thus the result of a comptation using one of these variable is undefined (we talk about [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)).